# MobX Store: Axios call is successful, but gets: Error getting data info:TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Tags: reactjs, axios, mobx, mobx-react

I am using MobX for state management with React. I actually got it working - data is propagated from the parent to children of this parent using `@observer` on the parent, and passing down props from the store. That's great!

Except.. The data is there - I can `console.log` it in each child, but the `axios.get` call inside the `stores.js` fails(even though it does pass the data?)

My `stores.js`:

```
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';
const axios = require('axios');

class Store {
    @observable dataForParent;
    loadParent = () => {
        let that = this;
        axios.get("/api/parentdata/snapshot").then(function(response){
            console.info("Received parent info "+ (new Date()).toString());
            that.dataForParent = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.error("Error getting parent info:" + error.toString());
        });
    };
}

export default Store;
```

And rightly so, it manages to pass data to the `<Parent />` component.

However, it never renders the `<Parent />` component because it says the `loadParent()` function actually catches an error.

The error being: `Error getting parent info:TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null`

This doesn't make much sense to me: I can `console.log` out the entire object containing other objects, gathered at the `/api/parentdata/snapshot` interface. Meaning the call is successful, rather than failing.

Why does it fail and block the entire application? The data is propagated to my React class. It seems strange to me.

Comment: Your observable data is called `dataForParent`, but you are assigning the response data to `parentdata`. It that a typo?

Comment: Yes that is a typo. Fixed it.